# How to Integrate 3rd party API in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm using wordpress and i want to integrate an SMS API into my wordpress site. Can anyone help in knowing where (in which file) to write the code for integration and also the code to integrate SMS API.

My SMS API Url is : 
`http://www.elitbuzzsms.com/app/smsapi/index.php?key=KEY&campaign=****&routeid=**&type=text&contacts=< NUMBER >&senderid=SMSMSG&msg=< Message Content >`

I want to integrate above API in my wordpress theme so that i can send sms based on mobile number and add required message.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I don't know how to use API in wordpress. I'm new to it. If you can help i will be thankfull

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In wordpress you can use [wp_remote_get](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/) and [wp_remote_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/)

get request example

```
$url = 'http://www.elitbuzzsms.com/app/smsapi/index.php?key=KEY&campaign=****&routeid=**&type=text&contacts=< NUMBER >&senderid=SMSMSG&msg=< Message Content >';

$response = wp_remote_get( $url  );
if( is_array($response) ) {
  $header = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
  $body = $response['body']; // use the content
}
```

post request example

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(),
    'body' => array( 'username' => 'bob', 'password' => '1234xyz' ),
    'cookies' => array()
    )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'Response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and can i know in which file should i write the above code in wordpress and if it is in functions.php do we need to use any hook or filter?

Comment: you can use it in functions.php or any of the file and it doesnt need to be hooked.